# Why is my useState variable initialized every time my React components is rendered?

Tags: reactjs

While working on some custom hooks in React I have observed the following behavior: Every time my component renders, my `useState` variables are initialized. More specifically, I have observed this by using an auxiliary function to dynamically create data for testing.

In order to demonstrate this behavior of React, I have created a super simple "TestComponent" (please refer to the code below). Every time my component renders, it logs "testData called!" in the console.

What did I do wrong? How can I prevent React from calling my "test-data-generating-function" `testData` every time my component renders?

PS: I tried to wrap my function `testData` into a `useCallback` hook. But that does not work since `useCallback` cannot be used at "top level". Also, instead of finding a "workaround", I would really like to understand the root cause of my problem.

```ts
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const testData = (): number[] => {
  console.log('testData called!');
  const returnValues: number[] = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    returnValues.push(i);
  }
  return returnValues;
};

const TestComponent = () => {
  // useState hooks
  const [data, setData] = useState<number[]>(testData());
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(1);

  // useEffect hook
  useEffect(() => {
    const increaseCounter = () => {
      setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
      setTimeout(() => increaseCounter(), 1000);
    };
    increaseCounter();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <p key={item}>{item}</p>
      ))}
      <p>{counter}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: Use `useMemo` if you don't want testData to be called for performance reason. If you look at your current code (it's just good old JavaScript), there's no way React could prevent testData from executing when TestComponent is called!

Comment: try write testData function inside TestComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what happens here is that your function to retrieve the data (`testData()`) is being called for each render, but not necessarily updates the state.
A react component is essentialy a function, and for each render the whole function is executed (including the call to `testData()`).
If you use the callback signature of `useState`, it will be called only on the first render:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(() => testData());
```